# How to store every output in a file while executing multiple tasks in playbook?

Tags: ansible

How to store every output in a file while executing multiple tasks in playbook?
1. I want to store every out in a file
2. In a playbook having different tasks also there.
3. Incrementally I want to store the output of playbook execution.

Comment: Could you please add more details to each query you have asked, So, that it becomes clear what all do you need when you say `I want to store every out in a file` and so for the remaining queries.

Answer (score 0):

Store each task output to a variable and then write to a file.
Just giving an idea below, not tested.

```
- name: Task1
  ...
  register: task_output1
- name: Task2
  ...
  register: task_output2
- name: Write to file
  copy: 
   content: "{{ item }}" 
   dest: /path/to/destination/file
  with_items:
   - task_output1.stdout_lines
   - task_output2.stdout_lines
```